# Postback does not occur due to heavy data (?)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, postback

On one of my application's ASP.NET page, I got a datagrid with 4 columns and 130 rows with each column containing a custom textbox (I know this is not the best practice).

There's a button which makes some calculation with this data.

I got my application deployed both to development server and test server.
Test server is located in another network and we need to use a VPN beforehand due to security reasons.

This troublesome page works without any problems on our development server (button does its job).

However on our test server, when I click the button, our AjaxLoadingPanel's gif never stops, as If the request takes forever to process or the request has been cut due to firewall or some other fancy security stuff.

I had to use,

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
```

in our webconfig because of the number of custom textbox controls on that page. So whenever I reduce the value of this key, I immediatly get 502 bad request from our application on the development server. So this key does its job and works as intended.

Both applications work without any problems on development server's and test server's local.
Only problem happens when I try to run the test application just by typing the url (accessing externally that is).

Both application's webconfigs are quite identical. Its not getting stuck on either maxRequestLength or maxRequestTimeout.

I think, It's kinda obvious that It's some sort of firewall or other security software/hardware related, blocking the request due to its size. (Amount of data sent to server for this operation is roughly 900KB)

What could be the problem, any ideas? Because I'm not getting any exceptions, the gif just never stops as I've mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's network monitor (F12 on chrome or Firebug on Firefox) under the XHR tab to see if the request has any answer whatsoever?

Comment: Well this has helped me track it down, was trying the operation on IE. When i tried with chrome, I instantly got an error saying : Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd

uncaught sys.webforms.pagerequestmanager server error exception status code returned from the server was : 0.

Comment: The thing is, why a i getting this only on test server but not on dev server :) Inspection continues.

Comment: If you have access to the IIS server logs, that would be helpful.

Comment: Weird stuff, just checked the logs, everyting looks fine, status codes are all 200.